# What are the white specks on my Strelitzia's leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, fungus

I have a white fungus on my *[Strelitzia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strelitzia)*. It started as little specks on the leaves and I would like to know what it is, what caused it and what will get rid of it.

Comment: Might be mealybug or scale or a fungal leaf spot - please provide more info and a clear photograph of the problem.

Comment: I've improved the grammar, but I agree - a photo would be very useful. As well as fungus, a number of insects could well be responsible.